# Parse retrieved Facebook friend details data

Tags: iphone, facebook, facebook-fql

I have used FQL query in order to retrieve the friends list at a time:

```
-(void)fetchSaveUserFriendDetails
{
 NSString* query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT uid,name,birthday_date FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())"];

 // Set up the query parameter
  NSDictionary *queryParam = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                    query, @"q", nil];
 // Make the API request that uses FQL
  [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/fql"
                                     parameters:queryParam
                                     HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                              completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                                  id result,
                                                  NSError *error) {
    if (!error)
    {
       NSLog(@"result is %@",result);

       NSArray *resultData = [result objectForKey:@"data"];
       if ([resultData count] > 0) {
       for (NSUInteger i=0; i<[resultData count] ; i++) {
          [self.friendsDetailsArray addObject:[resultData objectAtIndex:i]];
             NSLog(@"friend details are %@",friendsDetailsArray);
     }
   }
 }

        }];
 //Save friends to database stuff
 ..................
}
```

I get the below output:

[image]

I have gone through the official documentation of [Facebook Developers](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/run-fql-queries-ios-sdk/) FQL queries,but I am unable to find out how to parse the data.

I tried the below way to parse the retrieved data:

```
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:result encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *jsonValue = [jsonString JSONValue];
NSArray *values = [jsonValue objectForKey:@"friendinfo"];
```

where result holds all the friends data in JSON format,but I am getting below error:

**`-JSONValue failed. Error is: Unexpected end of input`**

**UPDATE-INFO**

I am trying to parse all the retrieved data(eventually JSON format) and save all the Facebook friends details to my database.All the implementation of retrieval and saving to db part is done in Facebook Sync button action.

Some assistance needed,any help is greatly applauded,thanks :)

Comment: What kind of database service are you using? If you happen to using Parse, for example, there is a pre-built method that does this kind of thing for you.

Comment: @jsksma2 I am using sqlite database,I need to fetch the Facebook friend details individually from what is retrieved in json format as shown in the screen shot of my post,then save those details in database

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update:**

```
- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result {
        if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]] && ([result count] > 0)) {
            result = [result objectAtIndex:0];
        }
        friends = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1];
        NSArray *resultData = [result objectForKey:@"data"];
        if ([resultData count] > 0) {
            for (NSUInteger i=0; i<[resultData count] && i < 25; i++) {
                [friends addObject:[resultData objectAtIndex:i]];
            }
            [friends retain];
            [tblInviteFriends reloadData];              
        } else {
                UIAlertView *alt=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"No Friends" message:@"You have no friends." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                [alt show];
                [alt release];
        }
}
```

and display that data in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` like bellow...

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[friends objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"]
```

define `yourDataArray` as a `NSMutableArray` and use it in `UITableView` for Data display

i hope this is helpful toy you...

Comment: Sorry Paras,I think I am troubling you a lot,I don't understand what the hell is wrong with me,earlier I have used graph object to fetch friend details and save to database,but that is taking time as it hits the Facebook server as many times as number of friends,hence I need to go for FQL query that fetches all the friends at a time and then store to database.So I am able to fetch the friends data,that's ok,but I need to parse the data,the code you gave didn't work.I think the problem is the "result" is of type id,but we are assigning as data.

Comment: @EshwarChaitanya try fql.query instead of :@"/fql"

Comment: I have changed @"/fql" to @"fql.query" and I get the result o/p as: Result: {
    "first_name" = Fql;
    gender = male;
    id = 100002399260168;
    "last_name" = Query;
    link = "https://www.facebook.com/fql.query";
    locale = "nb_NO";
    name = "Fql Query";
    "updated_time" = "2012-07-05T13:11:03+0000";
    username = "fql.query";
}
in console.

Comment: @EshwarChaitanya if you not get solution then just post the method in which you get this response... in which method you get it???

Comment: I am using FBRequestConnection and method "GET" to fetch the user friend details via FQL query,you can see the code in my post for clarification

Comment: I have debugged and found out that the control is not reaching if condition of our implementation,don't know the reason why,it is printing result,but control is not reaching our next statements,Please once check the updated part of my post

Comment: but plzz post the method where you get that result like - (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response  or - (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result methods..

Comment: I haven't used those methods Mr.Paras,please check the post once again,just made use of FBRequestConnection and HTTP method to get details that's it,I came across these methods at several instances,but I didn't find any need in implementing those methods as I was able to fetch friends details

Comment: @EshwarChaitanya see what i do when i want to get detail of friends from FB is above try to use the logic from that.. hope u understand and got solution...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27617/discussion-between-eshwar-chaitanya-and-paras-joshi)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're referring to using SQLite or Core Data specifically, but regardless, you need to serialize this data somehow. There are many methods & libraries that you can use. My personal favorite is to use Mantle as a baseline for my own models.

So, let's say I need to create a user object with the query response that I'm getting.

```
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/fql"
                             parameters:queryParam
                             HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                      completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                          id result,
                                          NSError *error) {
                          if (!error) {
                              NSMutableArray *users = [NSMutableArray array];
                              for (NSDictionary *userInfo in result) {
                                  User *user = [User modelWithRemoteDictionary:userInfo];
                                  [users addObject:user];
                              }
                          }
                      }];
```

Okay, so to break this down. You are using fast enumeration against the result object to get each dictionary individually. Then you are serializing that dictionary into a `User` object that you have created a model for. Mantle provides the `modelWithRemoteDictionary:`, which really just serializes the dictionary against keys in which you have preset as a private method in your `User` model, which then sets them to public properties of that same `User` model. Finally, each object is added to an array.

You're end product is that array, which you can use to do whatever you want.

I hope this helps!

**EDIT:**

Skipping the model:

```
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/fql"
                             parameters:queryParam
                             HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                      completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                          id result,
                                          NSError *error) {
                          if (!error) {
                              self.users = [NSMutableArray array];
                              for (NSDictionary *userInfo in result) {
                                  [self.users addObject:userInfo];
                              }
                          }
                      }];
```

For examples-sake, lets use `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` to display how you would use this array later on:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Allocate, and set the cell...

    NSDictionary *userDict = self.users[indexPath.row];

    cell.name = userDict[@"facebook_name"];
    cell.username = userDict[@"facebook_username"];
    cell.birthday = userDict[@"facebook_birthday"];
}
```

Comment: Sorry,but do we really need a model class(User),just want to assign the retrieved json output with name,id,birthdate to my strings

Comment: You can do that. I added in the model piece because without it, you are digging yourself a hole. If you later decide that you want to add an object to the dictionary by getting more FB info, then you have to go through the various calls that are identical to this one, and write out that extra line of code to use the data. 

If you still insist on not using a model for some reason, then switch out the use of the `User` object with an `NSDictionary`, set it's object for keys, and add it to the array.

Comment: Pardon,can you please explain it clearly,I am unable to get you actually I have facebookID,facebookName,facebookBirthday etc. strings,now I want to split the json data and assign those values accordingly,you can see in screen shot of my post,data is being fetched in JSON.Actually I have tried importing JSON.h file,and tried to assign this: NSMutableDictionary *dataDictionary = [result JSONValue]; and then assigned to my strings as follows: self.facebookID = [dataDictionary objectForKey:@"uid"]; self.facebookName = [dataDictionary objectForKey:@"name"] etc.but it doesn't work

Comment: That's probably because you are not enumerating the array of objects before trying to access their respective dictionary key values. See my edit for clarity. You can also post the error that you're getting, and I can most likely tell you exactly what you're doing wrong from that...

Comment: Sorry,the code:    if (!error){
                                      self.friendsDetailsArray = [NSMutableArray array];
                                      for (NSDictionary *userInfo in result) {
                                          [self.friendsDetailsArray addObject:userInfo];
                                      }
                                  } doesn't work for me as when I print the array,I get null,it may be with in the block or outside :(

Comment: Try adding an else statement with an error report in case you have setup FBRequestConnection wrong. You are getting null because result is null.

Comment: I am sorry once again,when I print result,I get the output as shown in the screen shot of my post

Comment: Okay, post a screenshot of the entire dictionary. Because if you are getting a result back, and ending up with null, then you have to be trying to access keys when you are not in the right place of the array or dictionary.

Comment: Please once check the screen shot of my post,if I print result I get all id's and friend details,so we are creating a dictionary and checking whether it is in the result or not,I think we are doing mistake here,and my doubt is we need to parse this json output I guess,the screen shot output is in the JSON format,you can observe that,so we need to work on these lines I guess,BTW,I am leaving for lunch,will be back in about 30 min's or so :)